# How to correctly change dynamic pod library to static?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, cocoapods, static-libraries

The third party library began to support only the static cocoapods library. Before that, it was connected as dynamic

After changing the dynamic library to a static one, such an error began to appear

Please help me figure this out:

`Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56`

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibility56'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework '<Name>'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework '<Name>'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework '<Name>'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56_$_<someName> in <ThirdPartyLibrary>.a(File.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56_$<ThirdPartyLibrary> in <ThirdPartyLibrary>.a(File.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56_$<ThirdPartyLibrary> in <ThirdPartyLibrary>.a(File.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56_$<ThirdPartyLibrary> in <ThirdPartyLibrary>.a(File.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56_$<ThirdPartyLibrary> in <ThirdPartyLibrary>.a(File.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56_$<ThirdPartyLibrary> in <ThirdPartyLibrary>.a(File.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56_$<ThirdPartyLibrary> in <ThirdPartyLibrary>.a(File.o)
      ...
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56_$_<ThirdPartyLibrary>, __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56_$_<ThirdPartyLibrary> , __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56_$_<ThirdPartyLibrary> )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

P.S.
My podfile doesn't contain line `use_frameworks!`

I have Xcode 14.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it was a problem with Xcode 14.2
The vendor's library now supports the minimum version of Xcode 14.3, and I built the application on Xcode 14.2

If you had this problem, you should update your Xcode to 14.3

Answer (score 0):

Add a Swift file to the app to let Xcode know that it needs to link in the Swift system libraries to satisfy the dependencies of the binary library.

Comment: I've added empty swift file. And it isn't resolve problem with `Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56
`

I think that the problem with linking to main target is a static library

Also, build failed with this logs:
`ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibility56'`
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework '<thirdPartyLib>'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework '<thirdPartyLib>'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework '<thirdPartyLib>'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
```

Comment: `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` might help

Comment: No, it didn't help unfortunately.
Still this error :(